# After deployment getting 404 error axios post

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

Currently, I'm trying to get axios data from node.js.  and i can get the result on local url , however after i build it and deploy it, the post method get 404 error.  so i tried to use get method to test it. it gets react html result .
it's totally okay when i do it on local.  but only it doesn't work when i build and deployment.

I assumed it's because proxy problem so i installed `http-proxy-middleware` library and
I try to set up `setupProxy.js` on my react folder.

this is the example from
"https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/"
[image]

but it still doesn't work.

i want to know what can make this issue.

```js
//node.js 

app.get("/test", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ hello: "Hello world" });
});


const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "index.html"));
});
```

```js
//react 

const getTest = () => {
    axios
      .get(`${backend}/test`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

Comment: What is the value of `backend`?

Comment: that's the domain

Comment: Is your React app built into the `dist` folder?

Comment: yes my react app built into the dist !

Comment: I'm using vite ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [proxy configuration](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) only applies to the webpack-dev-server you use when developing your React app...

> Keep in mind that `proxy` only has effect in development (with `npm start`), and it is up to you to ensure that URLs like /api/todos point to the right thing in production.

I would suggest just using the simpler version by adding this to your `package.json`

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

You should also make sure your Express app is configured to handle API requests in both dev and production modes. To do so, I'd recommend using the same routes as used in the requests from the front-end...

```js
app.get("/api/test", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ hello: "Hello world" });
});

// or even better

app.use("/api", myApiRouter);
```

Now your React app can make requests to `/api/test` in both development and production modes

```js
axios.get("/api/test").then(({ data }) => console.log(data));
```

In development mode, the proxy configuration will forward the requests to your Express app.

In production mode, your Express app will be serving the built React app via `express.static()` so they'll be on the same domain.